# Function or Method with unknown number of parameters

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to create a method with unknown number of parameters?

And if it this the case :

- How is it possible to get access to them within this method?
- Do they have to be from the same type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes & yes.

it is possible, and all of them must be the same type, if you need to pass various types use object datatype instead, and then unbox them within function.
use ParamArray:

```
' Accept variable number of arguments 
Function Sum(ByVal ParamArray nums As Integer()) As Integer 
  Sum = 0  
  For Each i As Integer In nums 
    Sum += i 
  Next 
End Function   ' Or use Return statement like C#

Dim total As Integer = Sum(4, 3, 2, 1)   ' returns 10
```

for more info see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct363x9h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered and probably most people come here regularly for answer. @pylover answer is correct, but to add on it, you can avoid looping through all the items, by simply calling the `Sum()` function. Thus;

```
Function Sum(ByVal ParamArray nums As Integer()) As Integer 
  Return nums.Sum()
End Function
```

When calling the function

```
Dim total As Integer = Sum(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

`total` returns `10`. Other Functions you can perform on it, includes `Max()`, `Min()`, etc