# How define a function to accept multiple bracketed strings

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a function that will accept an **unlimited** number of bracketed strings, below is an example of the call I wish to make but I cannot work out how this should be defined in the actual function:

```
Dim rtn as Object = MyFunction("String1")("String2")

Private MyFunction("<Need Help Here>") As Object

End Function
```

For more context, the parameters passed to my function then need to used to get a Value from a JObject as shown in the link below:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

So the code in the function would be for example:

```
Dim rtn=obj("person_id")("name")
```

Above would be 'person_id' passed in String1, 'name' passed in String2.

Comment: What's the point of this? Is `MyFunction("String1", "String2", ...)` not sufficient? See: [ParamArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/paramarray).

Comment: No, if you read my post I need to pass unlimited parameters

Comment: And if you read my comment carefully, you'll notice that the `...` part indicates "unlimited"/"dynamic" :) That's exactly what the `ParamArray` keyword does. The method signature should be something like `Private MyFunction(ParamArray items() As String) As Object` and you can call it as shown in my previous comment above. The only difference is that parameters are not "bracketed" (which is the part I was asking about its purpose).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function or Method with unknown number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893343/function-or-method-with-unknown-number-of-parameters)

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. I am trying to create a function that then uses the passed parameters to get a property name as shown in this link:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: You can access the items just like in a regular array. Here's a full demo: https://rextester.com/XPI8957

Comment: I tried this before posting here. This unfortunately fails when I try to then query the JObject as it is then in the wrong format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231268/discussion-between-shedspotter-and-41686d6564).

Comment: What you are seeing in the JsonObject is NOT a function call but multiple, inline `Array Indexers` using a short hand (or default method)

Comment: Thanks @JayV, how would I pass these parameters to a Function so that I could use them against a JObject within the Function?

Comment: Well, you are wanting to index an array of objects to extract a specific element. You know how deep the array needs to be navigated, so you need to pass that number of parameters in. It won't be possible to create a single line of code that can access any array to navigate down to a single element